# is not a function in electron chrome but not node console

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I'm using the npm package, [foreach-batch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreach-batch) in an electron project. I have the package installed and there is no `Cannot find module` error.

```
var forEachBatch = require('foreach-batch')
var stuff = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

forEachBatch(stuff, function(i) { console.log(i) }, 2, function(progress) {
  console.log(progress);
}, 1000);
```

The code runs as expected in the node console

```
$ node
> var forEachBatch = require('foreach-batch')
undefined
> var stuff = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
undefined
> 
> forEachBatch(stuff, function(i) { console.log(i) }, 2, function(progress) {
...   console.log(progress);
... }, 1000);
0
1
0.2
...
```

However, when I start up electron with a `npm start` and enter the same code in the chrome console. I receive an `Uncaught TypeError: forEachBatch is not a function`

[image: Uncaught TypeError: forEachBatch is not a function]

I'm new to Node and Electron, any insight that would help me understand the architecture better would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a problem with the module itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module does not return anything in a browser.

A bit of its code

```
var forEachBatch = function() { .... };
window.forEachBatch = forEachBatch;
```

So when you do this

```
var forEachBatch = require('foreach-batch')
```

then since the require function does not return anything you overwrite window.forEachBatch and it becomes undefined.

So try this instead

```
require('foreach-batch')
forEachBatch(...);
```

I haven't try it thou.

Comment: That worked, thank you for the explanation and help @Molda